# Opening sublime text 3 from a tmux session opens an empty file?

Tags: terminal, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, tmux, tmuxinator

Whenever I try to open any file from the terminal using sublime, for example: `subl ~/.zshrc`, it works fine BUT when I try to do the same thing from inside of a tmux session I get an empty blank file.

I saw many people asking related questions and blaming sublime, but what I just figured out is that it's not sublimes fault! it's the relation between sublime and tmux. so how can I fix this? does it requires some sort of permission or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Tmux does not have the root access to your system.

It opens Sublime for you but it doesn't show you the system files content.

You need to give it permission first.

Comment: How can I give it permission?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Dug around a bit and found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/522055/subl-w-doesnt-ever-un-block-when-running-under-tmux-on-os-x) on SU. Installing the ["Reattaching" Wrapper program](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) to allow access to the Mac OS X pasteboard seems to solve the issue.